# How do I add a posted by 'user.email' to my app index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, the index I'm referring to is in songs#index.html.erb.

**I'd like to add a line like this:**

```
posted by <%= song.user.email %> <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
```

**which at the moment is returning:**

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

**Song.rb snippit**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

   extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  acts_as_voteable

  belongs_to :user, class_name: User, foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :genre_songs
  has_many :genres, through: :genre_songs
```

**User.rb snippit**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs
  has_many :comments
```

**schema snippits**

```
create_table "users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                                  null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: ""
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid",                                 null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

 create_table "songs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "artist"
    t.text     "url"
    t.string   "track_file_name"
    t.string   "track_content_type"
    t.integer  "track_file_size"
    t.datetime "track_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "plusminus"
    t.string   "slug"
  end

  add_index "songs", ["slug"], name: "index_songs_on_slug", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your songs you list in index doesn't have its associated `user`, so the `song.user` returns `nil`.

To avoid this you should validate presence of user in `Song` model, or check if user exists in view, like this:

```
<% if song.user %>
  posted by <%= song.user.email %> <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
<% end %>
```

The approach depends on your application logic.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, now that I think of it. I used seed data to populate my test environment. So, might this work in production with real users associated with the songs? Just want to make sure the code looks right to, does it?

Comment: @Apane101 I expanded my answer a little bit to cover (I guess) your question.